# Star Wars: The Force Unleashed easiest ending on Sith Master?

Tags: star-wars-the-force-unleashed

I'm playing through Star Wars: TFU on Xbox 360 at the moment and am on my Sith Master run.  I'm wondering which of the final enemies

> The Emperor or Darth Vader

is easier to defeat on this setting?

> I fought the emperor on my first playthrough and took very little damage, so I'm  wondering if Vader provides more of a challenge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't based off a Sith Master play but I've played both on the same difficulty level and found Vader to be the harder fight of the two. The Emperor seemed to use very predictable patterns with obvious points where you were supposed to hit him. Vader was less so since it's a more one on one fight and lots of chance for random things to happen. Remember getting totally killed one time because I got too close between him and a wall and I couldn't recover after force attacks.